# why multi-thread cant improve a mmap task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, mmap

I have a big task, which need to read 500 files (50G in total).

for every file, i should read it out, and do some calculation according to data from file. just calculate, nothing else. and i can ensure tasks are independent, just share some signleton object to read(i think that wont be the problem).

currently, i use mmap to get the file content's start pointer, and loop to calculate.

in single thread, i run the task, cost 30s,

i run it in a thread_pool, it cost me 35s（6 thread）.

my machine is a 16G memory, 2.2G hz cpu with 8 thread.

I try a lot of setting, and carefully ensure the independent of tasks.

I am not so good at hardware, is there a hard limit about IO, that limit my speed? can anyone remind me is there anything i can read?

sorry, the code is too complex, i cant make a valid demo here.

Comment: Are you IO bound or CPU bound? If it's just IO, threads won't help. In fact it might make things worse since you now have *N* threads competing for the same IO resources. If your drives are slow and your CPU is fast, single-threaded might be the most efficient. If your drives are too fast for your CPU to keep up with one thread, consider threading, but do be aware that your machine might have a much faster drive than is typical.

Comment: This is where performance monitoring tools, even the built-in ones that come with your OS, can help. Look to see what the peak speed of your drive(s) are.

Comment: @tadman i check by iptop, but seems no disk write/read task. i think they had been cached into mem, which is quite odd, since no io bound, it shoule speed up

Comment: You need to find out more about the limits of your drive(s). SATA isn't always the best. NVMe can be spectacular.

Comment: Because the disk isn't multi-threaded.

Comment: You just discovered that `mmap()` isn't really fast.  I'm not sure why `mmap()` even developed the "mmap izz da fastest!" cult that it has, but `mmap()` has to do a lot of work setting up virtual memory mappings that a simple `read()` doesn't have to do. Sure, code based on `mmap()` is simple, but if you're not accessing the data many, many times, paying the price to create the necessary virtual page mappings necessary for `mmap()` is just going to slow you down if you only access the data once.  And if you're not going to read the data again, you can `open()` with `O_DIRECT` (maybe...)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the MAP_POPULATE flag on mmap to read ahead if you want to load the whole file or use madvise.

The most important hardware detail here is not mentioned, if you read from SSD or HDD but i assume you use a SSD, otherwise the thread pool code would be much much slower.

I don't understand why you use mmaping here. There are only three valid reasons to mmap a file, first the data structure on disk is complex and you like to poke around, which is slow as it makes read ahead much less efficient. You need shared memory between processes. Or you work on huge files and need the OS functionality to swap out data to the file when your system comes under memory stress (all databases just do it for only this single reason).

Comment: i can use mmap or open, just i perfer to use mmap to read file.   and i am SSD.

Comment: Yes you can, but mmap is not the API that is optimized for disk io.

Comment: @Lothar *mmap is not the API that is optimized for disk io*  Indeed.  The problem with `mmap()` is you have to pay a huge price to create virtual memory mappings for every page you want to read.  That's OK if you're going to access the data multiple times.  But if you're only going to read the data once, that's a price usually not worth paying.  `read()`/`pread()` and `O_DIRECT` will probably be faster for the read-once.